# How many actions per controller in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, controller, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I know the title of the question is kind of vague, but I couldn't think of anything cleaner. (And even though it might seem like a ZF question, it really just is a php MVC question.)

I recently migrated a project from ZF2 to ZF3. The main difference was the need of dependency injection in each model & controller. Since I now have injected all dependencies instead of calling them with the serviceLocator (which lazy-loads a service) I'm stuck with a couple of questions.

A couple of controllers now seem really bloated and are instantiating services they wont use. Simply because a different action needs a service the whole controller now instantiates a service. Even though instantiating a service isn't that performance-heavy it still feels like a waste.

My question is, and this basically has been a question of mine since I started working with MVC, how specific would you make a controller? How many actions per controller? Or in this case maybe: how many services per controller?

I'm now even thinking about splitting each controller up, so all actions have their own controller. Is this a good/bad idea?

Any Thoughts?

Comment: A controller is just a class like any other.  Taken more generically, any time you find yourself thinking "this class is really big and is doing a lot of different things" then you probably want to refactor it into smaller components.

Comment: A single dispatchable action per controller is reasonable, but if your concern is the overhead of loading services then you might wish to lazy load them: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/lazy-services/

Answer (score 1):

I personally go for keeping a Controller focussed on a single Action. But it should be able to do/call everything needed to complete the action.

For example, you have a Product Entity. For basic CRUD (I go for iCRUD, 'cause why not? :p), I would create 5 controllers: Index, Add, View, Edit, Delete (semantics whether you use Add/Create, View/Read, etc.).

The biggest one is Edit, which has to "get" an existing Product, load it into a Form and return it, just for setting up an edit page. On POST of data it would have to get existing Product, load it into the Form, get request data and load it into the form, validate, prepare for storage, store, and return a response.

But I choose to have it be able to do the entire thing, but have it focused on that Action.

You could, of course, have all of the (i)CRUD actions in a single controller and still correctly apply MVC. I, personally, find it cleaner to separate these out. From the Namespace you should be able to deduce what the class you're looking at is for anyway.

An example from a project below:

[image]

In my opinion, it's clear that here we're looking at the User module, Controller sub-namespace focused on the User object. (There are siblings to the User object in this module: Route, Role, etc.)

---

Must say, it has both pro's and con's to do this.

Pro's:

- Clean and clear where  you need to be for something
- Separation of Concerns
- Fairly DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
- Easy to re-use Action controllers for different subjects (e.g. create a more abstract "ViewController" and implement per subject: Product, User, Address, whatever)

Con's:

- Fairly DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) (see what I did there? Need to do that with preloading Forms and such as well)
- Additional configuration in frameworks such as Zend Framework 3 (additional Controller/Factory combinations to register)
- Takes longer to setup, refactoring is "more"